# Instantiation of RAM in FPGAs using VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I was attempting to implement a dual port RAM as guided in [this excellent blog post](http://danstrother.com/2010/09/11/inferring-rams-in-fpgas/). However, ModelSim is giving the following warning when compiling:

```
** Warning: fifo_ram.vhdl(24): (vcom-1236) Shared variables must be of a protected type.
```

I also seem unable to create this as a wave, indicating to me that the variable is not being recognised using my code below.

How can I correctly declare this variable as a "protected" type? Also, as a more general question about shared variables - is this variable shared between all entities in a design?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity fifo_ram is 
    generic (data : natural := 8;
             addr : natural := 16);

    port (w_clk : in std_logic;
          w_en : in std_logic;
          w_addr : in std_logic_vector (addr-1 downto 0);
          w_data : in std_logic_vector (data-1 downto 0);
          --
          r_clk : in std_logic;
          r_rdy : in std_logic;
          r_addr : in std_logic_vector (addr-1 downto 0);
          r_data : out std_logic_vector (data-1 downto 0));
end fifo_ram;

architecture rtl of fifo_ram is 
    -- shared memory
    type mem_type is array ( (2**addr) - 1 downto 0 ) of std_logic_vector(data-1 downto 0);
    shared variable mem : mem_type;

begin
    write: process (w_clk)
    begin 
        if (rising_edge(w_clk)) then 
            if (w_en = '1') then
                mem(conv_integer(w_addr)) := w_data;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process write;

end architecture;

----------------------------------------------

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity tb_fifo is 
    generic (data : natural := 8;
             addr : natural := 16);
end entity;

architecture testbed of tb_fifo is

    signal tb_w_clk, tb_w_en : std_logic := '0';
    signal tb_w_addr : std_logic_vector (addr-1 downto 0);
    signal tb_w_data : std_logic_vector (data-1 downto 0);
    signal tb_r_clk, tb_r_rdy : std_logic := '0';
    signal tb_r_addr : std_logic_vector (addr-1 downto 0);
    signal tb_r_data : std_logic_vector (data-1 downto 0);
begin 
    dut : entity work.fifo_ram(rtl)
        port map(tb_w_clk, tb_w_en, tb_w_addr, tb_w_data,
                 tb_r_clk, tb_r_rdy, tb_r_addr, tb_r_data);

    wclock : process is
    begin
        tb_w_clk <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        tb_w_clk <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
    end process wclock;

    wdata : process is
    begin
        tb_w_addr <= x"FFFF";
        tb_w_data <= x"AA";
        wait for 100 ns;
        tb_w_en <= '1';
        wait for 70 ns;
        tb_w_en <= '0';
        wait;
    end process wdata;

end architecture;
```

Comment: Why aren't you declaring _mem_ as a signal? I don't see any reason to use shared variable instead of a signal here.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know, I'm mostly just following examples at this stage.

Comment: Your 'excellent blog post' is a bit dated. In the 2002 revision of the VHDL standard shared variables have to be a protected type accessed through subprograms declared in the same declarative region that have the shared variable visible. There's likely a Modelsim flag to set compatibility to an older version of the standard (e.g. 1993)

Comment: Might I suggest you take a look at lpm_ram? Also are you trying to be as "cross platform" as possible or would altsyncram or the like be usefull?
This is of course moot if you are trying to learn VHDL and just want to implement a RAM because of that. In that case please disregard this comment.

Comment: Try the command "vcom -93 file.vhd" to set Modelsim in VHDL93 compatibility mode. However, you don't need shared variables. The only advantage of shared variable, in your case, would be a faster simulation which uses less memory, but it's unlikely to be an issue today, espicially for a FIFO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, having gone through the blog post I now understand why they're using shared variable instead of signals. Its because multiple processes are assigning to this variable, which is not possible in the case of a *reg* in Verilog or a *signal* in VHDL. In that case the synthesizer will produce an error complaining of multiple drivers for *mem*. But in order to use shared variable in this case, you'll have to declare it as protected. What you need to do is declare a protected data type, and then encapsulate your *mem* variable inside it, much like classes in object oriented languages. Here's an example of the protected data type:

```
type mem_envelope is protected        -- protected type declaration

variable mem : mem_type;

function GetVal( addr : integer ) return std_logic_vector(data - 1 downto 0);
function SetVal( addr : integer; val : std_logic_vector(data - 1 downto 0) ) return boolean; --may be used to indicate whether write was successfull or not

end protected mem_envelope;
```

Then declare a sharede variable of type mem_envelope and use *GetVal* and *SetVal* functions to read/write values to the memory inside your processes.

Comment: Multiple assignments to a signal are certainly legal and work in VHDL. However there are specific constraints on this and a recommended path to follow and if you don't already know the details it's probably not what you want. (summary : resolved type such as std_logic; tristate drivers `my_sig <= 'Z';` to allow other drivers to work; arbitration logic so every driver takes its turn; and in modern FPGAs, restricted to external signals (ports on device pins. Or read up all about "wired OR logic").

Comment: `Its because multiple processes are assigning to this variable, which is not possible in the case of a reg in Verilog or a signal in VHDL.`Your are not correct. That's the official coding example from Xilinx. See [UG901, page 95](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf#page=95) for more details and examples.

Comment: @wahab Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried to implement what you have described here, but I get a message "protected type declaration cannot contain variable"... Should I be declaring mem_envelope just after "architecture rtl of fifo_ram is"?

Answer (score 3):

Another way of implementing a True-Dual-Port (TDP) RAM is to use **one** process with **two** clocks.

```
signal ram          : ram_t;
signal a1_reg       : unsigned(A_BITS-1 downto 0);
signal a2_reg       : unsigned(A_BITS-1 downto 0);

....

process (clk1, clk2)
begin   -- process
  if rising_edge(clk1) then
    if ce1 = '1' then
      if we1 = '1' then
        ram(to_integer(a1)) <= d1;
      end if;

      a1_reg <= a1;
    end if;
  end if;

  if rising_edge(clk2) then
    if ce2 = '1' then
      if we2 = '1' then
        ram(to_integer(a2)) <= d2;
      end if;

      a2_reg <= a2;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

q1 <= ram(to_integer(a1_reg));      -- returns new data
q2 <= ram(to_integer(a2_reg));      -- returns new data
```

This is even synthezisable with Xilinx tools. Altera tools need the altsyncram macro for a proper TDP-RAM recognition.

Source: [PoC.mem.ocram.tdp](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/ocram/ocram_tdp.vhdl#L176-L200)