# Array implementation on FPGA using VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have following line in my *VHDL* code:

```
prbs_reg_feed <= prbs_reg_ip(byte_indx);
```

where

```
type reg_type is array (0 to 63) of std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);

signal prbs_reg_feed           : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);

signal prbs_reg_ip             : reg_type;
```

I want know the *FPGA* implementation of this.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get synthesised to a lot of combinational logic. This combinational logic will have nearly 600 inputs and 9 outputs.

With an FPGA synthesier, if you were to write some code around this line:

```
prbs_reg_feed <= prbs_reg_ip(byte_indx);
```

to make your code behave more like a RAM, then you would probably get a RAM. (You should read the report files output by your synthesiser to make sure.)

```
  process(clock) is
  begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
      if we = '1' then
        prbs_reg_ip(byte_indx) <= datain;
      end if;
     prbs_reg_feed <= prbs_reg_ip(byte_indx);
    end if;
  end process;
```

NB: this assumes `byte_indx` is an `integer`.

Answer (score 2):

With care, and some knowledge of your target FPGA, this will be implemented as a memory block instead of combinational logic.

A typical restriction is that the assignment
`prbs_reg_feed <= prbs_reg_ip(byte_indx);`
has to be placed in a clocked process, as the memory blocks are typically synchronous.

The only way to be sure is to take a few minutes and try synthesising this block on its own, and read the synthesis report. And if it doesn't work first try, read the documentation and experiment further.

[Some examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831020/instantiation-of-ram-in-fpgas-using-vhdl?rq=1) for RAM. ROM can be the same, but without any way to write it, and perhaps declaring `prbs_reg_ip` as a constant instead of a signal, for example

```
constant prbs_reg_ip : reg_type := ( 0 => X"C3", 1 => "80", 2 => "FF", ...);
```

For some FPGAs or FPGA tools, you may need to add an attribute to the signal (or type) representing the memory, for example

```
signal prbs_reg_ip             : reg_type;
attribute ram_style : string;
attribute ram_style of prbs_reg_ip : signal is "block"; -- or "distributed"
```

See [this Xilinx answer](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/54778.html) for an example of this.